# Import data from Excel to Word - format number with comma

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, format

I created a macro in VBA that allows me to choose a cell populated with a number and pull the number in that cell into a specific location in a word document.

However, when I run the macro, the number that is populated into Word is not formatted with commas to separate thousands (e.g. looks like "10000" but need to look like "10,000"). The number is already formatted with the commas in Excel but the format does not carry over into Word.

How can I format the number with commas when pulling data from Excel to Word?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Excel to Word()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Folder\qsn.docm")
    With wrdDoc

        'find text on word document
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "AL1"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute

        'now found, type text from designated cell
        .Application.Selection.TypeText ActiveSheet.Range("C2")

        'find text on word document
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "AL2"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute

        'now found, type text from designated cell
        .Application.Selection.TypeText ActiveSheet.Range("D2")

        If Dir("C:\Folder\QSN.doc") <> "" Then
            Kill "C:\Folder\QSN.doc"
        End If
        .SaveAs ("C:\Folder\QSN.doc")
        .Close ' close the document
    End With
    wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the number using the `Format` function.

```
.Application.Selection.TypeText Format(ActiveSheet.Range("C2"), "#,##0.00")
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try the following?

```
.Application.Selection.TypeText ActiveSheet.Range("C2").NumberFormat = "Standard"
```

Comment: Dennis, your suggestion unfortunately did not work, when I ran the macro, instead of importing the data from excel into word, the word "false" now appears in word where the data should have appeared.

Comment: Can you try the Cdbl-function:
.Application.Selection.TypeText Cdbl(ActiveSheet.Range("C2"))

That solved my issue I had in the past. It converts the value to a double, including 2 decimals.

Comment: someone else was able to solve the mystery, thanks for your help tho!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer the value in the cell, formatted how it is in the cell, use the cell's `Text` property instead of its (default) `Value` property:

```
.Application.Selection.TypeText ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Text
```